# Proof that $ [2x] + [2y] \ge [x]+ [x+y] + [y]$?

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I have to proof (or disprove) the following

$ [2x] + [2y] \ge [x]+ [x+y] + [y]$ for $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$. [x] and [y] means the floor-function.

Can I do the following?

(1) Assume $x,y \in [0,1]$, then [x] = [y] = 0 and $0 \le [x+y] \le 1$.

(2) First case:$ [x+y] = 0$, then $[2x] + [2y] \le [x] + [y]$

(3) Second case:$ [x+y] = 1$, then x,y or both x and y are greater than 1/2, which means: $[2x]+ [2y] \ge 1 = [x] + [x+y] + [y]$.

Thank you.

Comment: Is it the floor or the ceiling function? They are two different functions (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions).

Comment: for 1) take $x=y=1$ then $[x]=[y]=1\neq 0$??? so I believe 1) is not true.

Comment: Umm.. it should be the floor-function, sorry. We called it "Gauß-bracket", I thought it's floor-ceiling in english.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

- Assume that $x,y \in [0,1)$.
- If $\lfloor x + y \rfloor = 1$ then $x \geq \frac{1}{2}$ or $y \geq \frac{1}{2}$.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Hi - Oh, so with [0,1) it should be alright. Is it also correct that I suppoe $x,y \in [0,1)$ ?

Comment: @K.L. Yep, but you should fix the case $\lfloor x+y\rfloor  = 0$. However, this is easy, as the right side is $0$ and the left is non-negative.

Comment: One last question: Can I prove that if $x,y \in [0,1)$ the in-equation holds for ANY x,y ?

Comment: @K.L. No, but you can reduce any $x,y$ into $x',y'\in[0,1)$. You start with "let $x=a+x'$ where $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $x' \in [0,1)$" and then manipulate the inequality in a way to obtain one with $x',y'$ only.